# Easiest way to remove a chain master link / masterlink

Tags: chain, master-link

When I'm breaking a chain with a master link (to remove the chain from the bike), usually I can do it with my hands by pushing the links together until the master link comes apart. But sometimes it's trickier than others, and can be a recipe for sore thumbs.

I know there are special tools that help with this, but I'm curious if there's a trick I'm missing.

What is an easy, reliable way to un-do the master link (even when stuck), without any specialty master-link-specific tools?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the tension from the chain. One way is using a small piece of wire to slacken the chain such as this one made by Topeak:
[image]

which you hook in a few links to the left of the quick link and a few links to the right.

Another way is to use the [rear derailleur](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GnlOS5Bgn0). Then, just pinch them together and slide your fingers opposite ways.

If that still is too hard, you can use a tool like the [Park Tool MLP-1.2](http://www.parktool.com/product/master-link-pliers-mlp-1-2) or a pair of needlenose pliers as a substitute.